# Wait for function that makes use of settimeout to complete in javascript before rerunning it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please Assist.

I need to `wait` for an operation to finish before executing it again in javascript. These operations may be run at different times. Not all at once. I have a problem with running 2 operations at once since they execute at the same time.

Output should append text in a "textarea" using `settimeout`. It needs to wait for that to finish then starts typing the next text at whatever random index of the "arrayofrandomtext " array is called. Later on the "ProcessText(someint)" may still be called based on a keystroke etc.

- The existing text must be appended, not replaced at 0 instead appending 
  i.e Hello World. Something else....

```js
var index=0;
var arrayofrandomtext = ["Hello World","something else", "other stuff"];
   
   function ProcessText(someint){
   
  //These may run together
  next_letter(arrayofrandomtext[someint]);
  //wait to complete and rerun it with other text
  next_letter(arrayofrandomtext[someint]);


  //later on if the user hits a key this may run only
  next_letter(arrayofrandomtext[someint]);
}

function next_letter(text){

  if (index <= text.length) {
    someControl.value = text.substr(0, index++);
    setTimeout(function () { next_letter(text); }, 50);

 }
}
```

Comment: what is this `someControl.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an array of text values , using `Array.prototype.slice()` to create copy of initial array of text values ; `Array.prototype.shift()` to set text parameter for `next_letter` ; if array has `.length` after inital call to `next_letter` , recursively call `ProcessText`

```js
var arr = ["Hello...", "Some other text"],
  copy = arr.slice(),
  button = document.querySelector("input")
  someControl = document.querySelector("textarea"),
  index = 0;

function ProcessText() {
  next_letter(copy.shift())
}

function next_letter(text) {

  if (index <= text.length) {
    someControl.value = text.substr(0, index++);
    setTimeout(function() {
      next_letter(text);
    }, 50);
  } else {
    index = 0;
    if (!!copy.length) {
      ProcessText()
    } else {
      copy = arr.slice();
    }
  }

}

button.onclick = ProcessText;
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" /><br />
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you already have done this - but I'd like a working version for demonstration.  You can write a recursive function, which calls settimeout on itself after it has finished.  For example, given a function which logs out each letter of a string.

```
var log = function(text, index, duration) {
  console.log(text[index]);

  if (index < text.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      log(text, index + 1, duration);
    }, duration);
  }
};

log("Hello There", 0, 1000);
log("Nice to see You", 0, 1000);
```

Now of course, if you run this code, the second log function will not wait for the first.  You can use Promises and/or Callbacks to perform async control flow.  First modify the log function to take a callback as a parameter.

```
var logCB = function(text, index, duration, cb) {
  console.log(text[index]);

  if (index < text.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      logCB(text, index + 1, duration, cb);
    }, duration);
  } else {
    cb();  //execute callback
  }
};
```

Now if you pass your second function (wrapped in another function to delay execution). as a parameter to your first, it will execute after it has finished.

```
var cb = function() {
  logCB("Nice to see you", 0, 1000);
};

logCB("Hello, World!", 0, 1000, cb);
```

While this works, it can become unwieldy for multiple nesting.  A better solution is to use a promise - you only need to wrap your logCB in another function.  Here f is a logCB.

```
var promiseLog = function(f, text, delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     f(text, 0, delay, resolve);
  });
};
```

Then ... we can chain them together to wait for completion with .. Then.

```
promiseLog(logCB, "Hello World", 1000)
 .then(function() {
   return promiseLog(logCB, "Hey There", 1000)
 });
```